# Is there any way to speed up a copy function that just makes a new instance of a class

Tags: c#, optimization

I'm making a chess AI, and currently the limiting factor on my code is the copy function for the board. I'm calling this function hundreds of thousands of times, so I need the code to be as fast as possible. My current method is to just create a new instance of the class and copy over all the parameters, but this is too slow for my purposes, usually running at about 0.014 ms. Is there any way to speed up this code, or will I need to rethink how my code works? Thanks!

Implementation for Board.copy():

```
        Piece[] whiteArrCopied = pieceCopy(this.whiteArr);
        Piece[] blackArrCopied = pieceCopy(this.blackArr);
        Piece[] pieceArrCopied = new Piece[32];
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            pieceArrCopied[i] = whiteArrCopied[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            pieceArrCopied[i + 16] = blackArrCopied[i];
        }
        Board ret = new Board(pieceArrCopied, whiteArrCopied, blackArrCopied);
        if (lastMove != null)
            ret.lastMove = lastMove.copy();
        else
            ret.lastMove = null;
        if (lastMoveBeforeMove != null)
            ret.lastMoveBeforeMove = lastMoveBeforeMove.copy();
        ret.capturedInstance = capturedInstance;
        if (legalMoves != null)
            ret.legalMoves = copier(legalMoves);
        ret.halfMoves = halfMoves;
        ret.fullMoves = fullMoves;
```

Implementation for pieceCopy():

```
    public Piece[] pieceCopy(Piece[] arr)
    {
        Piece[] ret = new Piece[arr.Length];
        for (int i=0; i<ret.Length; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = arr[i].copy();
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Implementation for Piece.copy():

```
        Piece ret = new Piece(loc.ToArray(), this.color == "white", this.type);
        ret.two = this.two;
        ret.enPassant = this.enPassant;
        ret.dead = this.dead;
        ret.moved = this.moved;
        ret.castle = this.castle;
        return ret;
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please share the relevant types?

Comment: I am not that versed into chess AI, there could be a better algorithm that doesn't require that many copies. Anyway if you want to keep your algorithm, presuming you don't keep all of these copies (e.g. you constantly create and destroy) you could keep a pool a a few hundreds or thousands of board objects and reuse them.

Comment: Personally I have to recommendations - consider pooling and/or switching to structs (and `Array.Copy`).

Comment: As you have working code, I wonder if this question would be better placed on [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But, one little thing that might speed it up is to use an Enum instead of a string for `color`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton On Code Review we want to see at least complete functions, it this case we would probably want to see the entire class including the using statements. before posting on Code Review please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).